# Cannot set toolbar title when using include for toolbar.xml

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I am using the following setup to theme my toolbar in toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:title="@string/app_name"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in layout my_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        app:title="@string/my.toolbar.title"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        >
    </include>
</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the title of the toolbar does not get the value of my.toolbar.title.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include suggest that you can override any android: attributes but what about app: .

Note: I have also tried to use android:title instead of app:title and still no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: The include tag doesn't know what you're including, it just includes the layout. You have to set the title in the toolbar xml file

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programmatically:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your title");
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to do that. I prefer to keep it in the XML.

Comment: @checklist why do you want to keep it in xml. This toolbar can be used in different screens and each screen will have its own title. just my opinion.. You can look at the attributes available @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: Proper separation requires the title to be set in the xml. Hence, I prefer it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `<merge>` tag around the toolbar, that will allow you to use the tags that you would use on the toolbar in the include tag.